# Is it possible to disable a specific Roslyn analyzer using editorconfig?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, editorconfig

According to [MSDN's .NET code analysis documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022), we can configure the behavior of Roslyn analyzers through the `.editorconfig` file.

- We can configure individual rules: `dotnet_diagnostic.<rule ID>.severity = <severity>`
- We can configure category rules: `dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-<rule category>.severity = <severity>`
- We can configure all the rules: `dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = <severity>`

But I can't find any mention of configuring a specific analyzer's rules.

Let's say I have a directory in my project that shouldn't be analyzed by Roslynator, and another one that shouldn't be analyzed by StyleCop. By this, I mean that *every single rule* of those analyzers should be disabled for their respective directory. Some of these analyzers have hundreds of rules, disabling all of them individually would take forever.

*Note: This is just an example, my question is about whether I can target any arbitrary analyzer, not whether StyleCop or Roslynator have their own settings to do this.*

Inside my `.editorconfig` file, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
# Disable all Roslynator analysis in Foo/ directory
[/Foo/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer.Roslynator.severity = none

# Disable all StyleCop analysis in Bar/ directory
[/Bar/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer.StyleCop.severity = none
```

Does such a feature exist? Or do I have to disable all analysis for those directories?

Comment: put `.editorconfig` files in each directory - they will inherit parent directory

Comment: stylecop can be handled in .editorconfig the same way as the roslyn analyzers with:
dotnet_diagnostic.SA0001.severity = silent # xml comments

because stylecop supports this directly, not sure if this is supported by Roslynator

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt I used StyleCop and Roslynator as examples. I want to know if there's a standard C#/.NET `.editorconfig` rule that can apply to any arbitrary analyzer. Updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not really sure how that's related to the question? I'm trying to disable specific analyzers in specific directories without having to manually specify every single rule these analyzers have.

Comment: Just tried with an internal developed one and simply using dotnet_diagsnostics.RULEID.severity = silent worked for me. The codebase for the internal developed on for sure don't have any code reading .editorconfig so it just worked. I just took RULEID from dependencies -> analyzers for our custom rule.

reading your comment to Daniel, I don't think that is possible, you have to specify all the rules in an editorconfig file.

Comment: if you want to disable them then put it in the directory that it applies to

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt Yeah, the question might've been worded poorly. I've updated the question to specify that I meant configuring *every* rule of a specific analyzer at once (i.e. disabling all of StyleCop) instead of individual rules (of which there might be hundreds, depending on the analyzer).
Hoping there's a way, but it seems like I might have to find a full list of every single rule for the analyzers we're using and dump them in the `.editorconfig` files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way for that using `.editorconfig`. But you can remove the analyzer reference completely for specific *projects* using an MSBuild target that runs before `CoreCompile` target.

```xml
<Target Name="RemoveAnalyzerReference" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Analyzer.NugetPackageId)'=='ANALYZER_NUGET_PACKAGE_ID'"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Note that this applies to a given project, not directory. There is a distinction between the two in that a project can reference something outside its directory.

Also note that you can use `Directory.Build.targets` if you have multiple projects in a directory where you want this to apply to all of these projects.